# XSLT by HEAT updates temp file but doesn't filter files at publish dir

Tags: xslt, wix

I was using [this](http://blog.bartdemeyer.be/2013/10/create-an-installer-for-website-with-wix-part-1/) manual for creating WIX Web App Installer. Now I want to filter files published by heat.exe using XSLT. My XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:key name="extra-configs-search" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.config')]" use="@Id" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('extra-configs-search', @Id)]" />
    <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('extra-configs-search', @Id)]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And I run it by following command:

```
"path-to-wix-toolset\heat.exe" dir $(Publish) -dr INSTALLFOLDER -ke -srd -cg MyWebWebComponents -var var.publishDir -gg -t ExcludeExtraFiles.xsl -out $(WebSiteContentCode)
```

As a result temp file *WebSiteContent.wxs* updates as expected but Publish folder **still contains files I want to filter**. What I'm doing wrong? May be *WebSiteContent.wxs* get updated too late but how to fix it?

**EDIT:** (candle and light commands I use)

```
"path-to-wix-toolset\candle.exe" -ext WixIISExtension -ext WixUtilExtension -ext WixSqlExtension -dpublishDir=$(Publish) -dMyWebResourceDir=. @(WixCode, &apos; &apos;)

"path-to-wix-toolset\light.exe" -ext WixIISExtension -ext WixUtilExtension -ext WixSqlExtension -cultures:en-us -loc en-us.wxl -ext WixUIExtension -out $(MsiOut) @(WixObject, &apos; &apos;)
```

Comment: publish folder? What do you mean? If you build your MSI, the necessary files will be included. heat does not remove anything, all it does is apply transformation to the *.wxs file and that's it.

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa Ok, I see. But why transformation to the *.wxs is applied but the built MSI still includes the filtered files? See my update, I've added candle and light commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, this code works well! I've changed the name of MSI, but still called the old one by command line. Shame on me :) 
You can use it as a next step of [this](http://blog.bartdemeyer.be/2013/10/create-an-installer-for-website-with-wix-part-1/) manual if you need to filter files to publish.